# Pandas - Binary Matrix and String Data (how to stack string data / new line?)

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to generate a particularly structured dataframe, but i cant seem to "stack" the data. My sample raw data:

```
# raw data
df = pd.DataFrame({'Name':['name1', 'name2', 'name3', 'name1', 'name2', 'name3', 'name1', 'name2', 'name3' ], 
                   'Year':['freshman','sophomore','freshman', 'freshman','sophomore','freshman', 'freshman','sophomore','freshman'], 
                   'Rotation':['ERJD','PEDI','MAM','PEDI', 'ERJD','PEDI','MAM','ERJD','ABD'],
                   'Week1':[1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0],
                   'Week2':[0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0],
                   'Week3':[0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1],
                   'Week4':[1,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1]
                  })
df = df[['Name','Year','Rotation','Week1','Week2','Week3','Week4']]
```

Which looks like:

```
    Name    Year    Rotation    Week1   Week2   Week3   Week4
0   name1   freshman    ERJD      1       0       0       1
1   name2   sophomore   PEDI      1       0       0       0
2   name3   freshman    MAM       1       0       0       0
3   name1   freshman    PEDI      0       1       0       0
4   name2   sophomore   ERJD      0       1       0       0
5   name3   freshman    PEDI      0       1       0       0
6   name1   freshman    MAM       0       0       1       0
7   name2   sophomore   ERJD      0       0       1       1
8   name3   freshman    ABD       0       0       1       1
```

I reshape the dataframe:

```
#Reshape Table + Filtering
df = pd.melt(df, 
             id_vars=['Name','Year','Rotation'], 
             value_vars=list(df.columns[3:]),
             var_name='Week', 
             value_name='Sum of Value')

df = df.loc[df['Sum of Value'] == 1].reset_index()
df.pop('index')
```

Which Generates:

```
    Name    Year    Rotation    Week    Sum of Value
0   name1   freshman    ERJD    Week1       1
1   name2   sophomore   PEDI    Week1       1
2   name3   freshman    MAM     Week1       1
3   name1   freshman    PEDI    Week2       1
4   name2   sophomore   ERJD    Week2       1
5   name3   freshman    PEDI    Week2       1
6   name1   freshman    MAM     Week3       1
7   name2   sophomore   ERJD    Week3       1
8   name3   freshman    ABD     Week3       1
9   name1   freshman    ERJD    Week4       1
10  name2   sophomore   ERJD    Week4       1
11  name3   freshman    ABD     Week4       1
```

I create a pivot table:

```
#Create Pivot
pivot = df.pivot_table(index=['Rotation','Year'], columns='Week', values='Name', aggfunc=lambda x: ' '.join(x))
pivot = pivot.reindex(weeks, axis=1) # Change order of Columns
pivot
```

Which generates:

```
                    Week1       Week2      Week3    Week4
Rotation    Year                
ABD       freshman   None        None      name3    name3
ERJD      freshman  name1        None       None    name1
          sophomore  None       name2      name2    name2
MAM       freshman  name3        None      name1     None
PEDI      freshman   None  name1 name3      None     None
          sophomore name2        None       None     None
```

I would like to stack the names within the table, **for instance Week2 PEDI has** `name1` and `name3` **side by side. How can i put the names on different lines?** Is there a better way to go about this instead of using the pivot table? Is the `pd.melt` step even necessary?

**Desired Structure:**

```
                    Week1       Week2      Week3    Week4
Rotation    Year                
ABD       freshman   None        None      name3    name3
ERJD      freshman  name1        None       None    name1
          sophomore  None       name2      name2    name2
MAM       freshman  name3        None      name1     None
PEDI      freshman   None        name1      None     None    
                                 name3
          sophomore name2        None       None     None
```

Thanks in advance for the help!

**SOLUTION:**

After `pd.melt` , do the following:

```
df['aggval'] = df['Week'].map(str) + df['Rotation']
df['aggval'] = df.groupby(['aggval']).cumcount()+1
pivot = df.pivot_table(index=['Rotation','aggval'], columns='Week', values='Name', aggfunc=lambda x: ' '.join(x)).fillna('')
pivot = pivot.reindex(weeks, axis=1)
```

Comment: How would you expect that output to be queried?

Comment: @rahlf23 Right now this is all testing in a jupyter notebook. The dataframe generated after pd.melt will be the results that are stored in the database. The  customer is requesting the results to be shared in the desired structure somehow, if possible. I just don't know if it is.

Comment: My point here being that you are trying to add a nested index level here by having the names take up multiple rows. I doubt that querying this information in this manner is what you want.

Comment: @rahlf23 it isnt what i want, its specifically what is being requested. Is it possible?

Comment: @rahlf23 would it make a difference if index 'Year' was removed from the table, leaving only 'Rotation' in index ?

Comment: You could create a Multiindex with name as the third level. That would probably be the most readable (i.e. `('Rotation','Year','Name')` as your levels )

Comment: @rahlf23 Adding 'Name' as the third level index wont work since the names will need to be under the weeks they are scheduled. The real dataset is a 52 week schedule across 50 different people and 21 different rotations, so the desired structure is being requested to make it easier to review.

Comment: In that case, I would change `' '.join(x)` to `x.tolist()`. BTW: `reset_index(drop=True)` removes the index column after resetting, so you don't have to do `df.pop('index')` separately

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After pd.melt , do the following:

```
df['aggval'] = df['Week'].map(str) + df['Rotation']
df['aggval'] = df.groupby(['aggval']).cumcount()+1
pivot = df.pivot_table(index=['Rotation','aggval'], columns='Week', values='Name', aggfunc=lambda x: ' '.join(x)).fillna('')
pivot = pivot.reindex(weeks, axis=1)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could loop through the weeks that you are interested in and conditionally populate your dataframe, like so:

```
for week in ['Week1','Week2','Week3','Week4']:
    df[week] = np.where(df[week]==1, df['Name'], df[week])
```

This gives:

```
    Name      Year Rotation  Week1  Week2  Week3  Week4
0  name1  freshman     ERJD  name1      0      0  name1
1  name2  sophmore     PEDI  name2      0      0      0
2  name3  freshman      MAM  name3      0      0      0
3  name1  freshman     PEDI      0  name1      0      0
4  name2  sophmore     ERJD      0  name2      0      0
5  name3  freshman     PEDI      0  name3      0      0
6  name1  freshman      MAM      0      0  name1      0
7  name2  sophmore     ERJD      0      0  name2  name2
8  name3  freshman      ABD      0      0  name3  name3
```

Then you can group your dataframe and store the string-type entries in lists:

```
grouped = df.drop('Name', axis=1).groupby(['Rotation','Year']).agg(lambda x: [i for i in x if type(i)==str])
```

Which gives:

```
                     Week1           Week2    Week3    Week4
Rotation Year                                               
ABD      freshman       []              []  [name3]  [name3]
ERJD     freshman  [name1]              []       []  [name1]
         sophmore       []         [name2]  [name2]  [name2]
MAM      freshman  [name3]              []  [name1]       []
PEDI     freshman       []  [name1, name3]       []       []
         sophmore  [name2]              []       []       []
```

Note that there is an error in your desired output in your OP. There is no `('MAM','sophmore')` group. Also note that `'sophmore'` is spelled `'sophomore'`, just for clarity.

Comment: thanks for providing a different approach and catching my spelling error. I made updates to the post. Your proposed solution didnt stack the names. I was able to do so, providing the solution above.

Comment: You bet. If this solution helped you I would appreciate the upvote / check mark. I would also be interested in seeing your final solution.

Comment: Will do when i get enough points to do so. I apparently don't have enough points to upvote yet...

Comment: @Steve your solution looks good.  I think it would be worth posting as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using `set_index` and `mul`:

```
df1 = df.set_index(['Rotation','Year'])

df1.filter(like='Week').mul(df1['Name'], axis=0)\
  .replace('',np.nan)\
  .sort_index()
```

Output:

```
                     Week1  Week2  Week3  Week4
Rotation Year                                 
ABD      freshman     NaN    NaN  name3  name3
ERJD     freshman   name1    NaN    NaN  name1
         sophomore    NaN  name2    NaN    NaN
         sophomore    NaN    NaN  name2  name2
MAM      freshman   name3    NaN    NaN    NaN
         freshman     NaN    NaN  name1    NaN
PEDI     freshman     NaN  name1    NaN    NaN
         freshman     NaN  name3    NaN    NaN
         sophomore  name2    NaN    NaN    NaN
```